# Why do I get an exception when I reference DataGridView CurrentRow?

Tags: winforms, exception, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to get a "changed currentcell" event in `DataGridView`, but every time I try to load the form (which is a child of another form), I get an exception in the `datagridview_currentcell` event:

> SystemNullReferenceException: object not set to an instance of an object.

I guess it's because I haven't selected any row. Of course I can use `catch` and `try` to bypass, but I want a more elegant way and to know what am I doing wrong.

Here's my code:

**Form2.CS**:

```
namespace AsefotSystem
{
    public partial class ownerReport : Form
    {
        public ownerReport()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadDB();
            setGrid();
        }

        private void loadDB()
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            OleDbConnection connection;
            OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string sql2 = null;
            connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RiskDB"].ConnectionString;              
            sql2 = "select * From tbl2_asefot";
            connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, connection);
                oledbAdapter.Fill(ds, "Asefot");
                oledbAdapter.Dispose();

                connection.Close();
                dsAsefotGrid = ds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void setGrid()
        {
            Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dsAsefotGrid.Tables[0];
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CurrentCell(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        DataSet dsAsefotGrid;
    }
}
```

**Form2.Designer.CS:**

```
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CurrentCell);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `try{}` `catch{}`, you could test if the `CurrentCell` or even `CurrentRow` is not `null`.

```
    if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataGridView` Cell has no value and you are trying to save a string of `null`.

Try catching the exception and inform the user that he has to write something in the cell

```
try
{
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.
    CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
catch(NullReferenceException)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("You cannot process an empty cell");
}
```

Please find more information under the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sxw2ez55(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):